# What is the probability distribution used in logistic regression called?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, logistic, density-function, logistic-distribution

In logistic regression, we set the probability of predicting a target $y$ given a data $x$ as,

$\Pr(Y = 1|X;w) = \dfrac{\exp(w^TX)}{(1+\exp(w^TX))}$

What is exactly this probability distribution (or more accurately, conditional probability mass function) called?

I tried to look up logistic distribution but it doesn't look the same https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_distribution

Comment: The response variable y is a Bernoulli variable. You are predicting the probability of belonging to one of two particular classes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/112058/7071) helpful. It gives the latent utility derivation for binary choice model, and shows where the logistic CDF comes from in modeling Bernoulli variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $Y_i$ is a binary variable, its distribution is the [Bernoulli distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution):

$$Y_i | \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{w} \sim \text{Bern} \Bigg( \text{Prob} = \frac{\exp(\mathbf{w}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})}{1 + \exp(\mathbf{w}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})} \Bigg).$$

One alternative way of looking at the logistic regression is to regard the observed response variable as a discretisation of an underlying "latent variable", where the latter has a [logistic distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_distribution).  In this (equivalent) alternative formulation, we have an observed response variable $Y_i \equiv \mathbb{I}(\tilde{Y}_i > 0)$, with the underlying latent response having the distribution:

$$\tilde{Y}_i | \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{w} \sim \text{Logistic} \Bigg( \text{Location} = \mathbf{w}^\text{T} \mathbf{x}, \ \text{Scale} = 1 \Bigg).$$

Comment: Thank you. Just to clarify. This is the conditional distribution of $Y$ (conditioned on $X$) and not $Y$ itself. Is there a way that we can even talk about the distribution of $Y$ itself (since the distribution of $X$ is usually unknown, as $X$ could simply be some vectorized image).

Comment: Yes, in regression analysis the distributions are all conditional on $\mathbf{x}$.  The only way to get the marginal distribution of the response variable is to specify a distribution for $\mathbf{x}$, and then apply the law of total probability.  Note that this takes you out of regression analysis and into the territory of multivariate analysis.

Comment: ... And even in the latter case, $Y$ is still binary, so its marginal distribution would still be a Bernoulli distribution (albeit with a different probability parameter).

Answer (score 2):

In your link, you have the cumulative distribution function for the logistic distribution as $$\frac{1}{1+e^{-\frac{x-\mu}{s}}}$$

while in your question you have $$\dfrac{\exp(w^TX)}{(1+\exp(w^TX))} \text{ which is } \dfrac{1}{1+e^{-w^TX}}$$

and these are essentially the same so long as $w^TX$ has mean $0$ and variance $1$.

You can see that the first expression is a cumulative distribution function and this expression approaches $0$ when $x$ is very negative but approaches $1$ when $x$ is large and positive.  This is what want from your logistic regression: the predicted conditional probability of a positive result $(Y=1)$ increases towards $1$ as $w^TX$ increases