# What is the correct procedure for adding random noise to observed predictor data in order to generate binary response data?

Tags: r, distributions, random-generation

Suppose we have an observed data matrix $X$ of length $N$ with $2$ column predictors. If I wanted to generate continuous response data from this, we might do

$$
Y^{cont} = X\beta + N(0,1)
$$

or in `R`

```
Y = beta1*X[,1] + beta2*X[,2]  + rnorm(N, 0, 1)
```

If instead I wanted to generate binary response data, is it valid to do

$$
Y^{bin} = Bin[\sigma(X\beta + N(0,1))]
$$

or in `R`

```
Y = rbinom(N, 1, sigmoid(beta1*X[,1] + beta2*X[,2]  + rnorm(N, 0, 1)))
```

where

```
sigmoid = function(x) 1/(1+exp(-x))
```

is the sigmoid function? How can I effectively add noise to data in order to generate binary data?

Comment: `rbinom` already adds noise, it produces (pseudo-) random numbers. See also this recent post:https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/481391/11849