# Parametric bootstrap for logistic regression

Tags: logistic, bootstrap

I am trying to do parametric bootstrap for logistic regression but I don't know what the random error terms should be. I know how to do it with linear regression since the error terms follow a normal distribution. Really appreciate any pointers to resources about this topic. Thanks

Comment: There are no explicit error terms in logistic regression. [Why do we model noise in linear regression but not logistic regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/481391/237901)

Comment: You can find [many posts here about bootstrapping in logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=logistic+regression+bootstrap).  Likely some will help you.