# Binary $Y$ but normal residuals?

Tags: regression, distributions, normal-distribution, residuals, qq-plot

In regression, it is abundantly clear that $Y$ can be non-normal while the residuals $\epsilon = Y - \beta_0 - \beta_1 X$ are normal. But can $Y$ be *binary* when the $\epsilon$ are normally distributed?  This question is motivated by students' regression projects where their $Y$ was quite discrete, and obviously non-normal for that reason, yet their residual histogram and *q-q* plots "looked normal." Here is a simulation to illustrate:

```r
par(mfrow=c(1,2)); set.seed(12345) 
X = rnorm(1000, 3, 1); Y = round(X + rnorm(1000,0,1)) 
table(Y) # Y is highly discrete and obviously non-normal 
model = lm(Y ~ X) 
 ## But the diagnostic plots and tests suggest normality is reasonable 

qqnorm(model$residuals, main= "Residual q-q Plot"); qqline(model$residuals) 
shapiro.test(model$residuals); plot(X,Y, main = "Raw Scatterplot")
```

Despite the large sample size ($n=1000$), the Shapiro test "accepts" normality ($p = 0.1228$), and the normal *q-q* plot looks fine. However, the raw scatterplot shows obviousness discreteness, and hence, obvious nonnormality that is not discernable from the analysis of the residual distribution.

[image: Discrete Y]

I am pretty sure that the actual distribution of $\epsilon$ is not precisely normal in my example, but *could it be normal*?

How bad can this problem be? In the most extreme case, suppose $Y$ is *binary* (0 or 1), and a linear predictor is $\beta_0 + \beta_1 X$. Is it *possible* that $\epsilon = Y - \beta_0 - \beta_1 X$ has precisely a normal distribution in this case?

Comment: $Y$ in my problem statement is either 0 or 1. The predictor which gives the residual is linear, but the problem could also be stated in terms of a nonlinear predictor. But that does not change the essential issue, and it makes the math harder.

Comment: Of course $Y$ can be binary!  Simply begin with arbitrary binary $Y$ data $(y_i)$ and the Normal errors $\epsilon_i,$ pick $(\beta_0,\beta_1),$ and set $x_i = (y_i - \epsilon_i - \beta_0)/\beta_1.$  Done.

Comment: Very nice.  But I should revise my question though for better realism.  To correspond with the intended application of the naïve student who performs the regression and concludes "approximately normal $Y$" based on the residual plots, the $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ should correspond to a (theoretical) line of best fit. I don't think they need to be identified explicitly, though.

Comment: In  my comment, the $\beta_i$ define a "theoretical line of best fit," so I don't understand the distinction you are trying to make.  It is true that if you were to use OLS to fit these data, the residuals wouldn't look at all Normal -- but the reason is that a fundamental assumption of OLS (and most regression models) is strongly violated: the $x_i$ and $\epsilon_i$ will have a strong correlation; the $\epsilon_i$ will not be independent. If you insist the $\epsilon_i$ be independent, then they cannot be Normally distributed.

Comment: Please run: y=rbinom(1000,1,.5); eps=rnorm(1000); b0=2; b1=3; x=(y-eps-b0)/b1;
plot(x,y); abline(b0,b1); abline(lsfit(x,y), lty=2)  . The least squares fit is very different from your $\beta_0+\beta_1x$ line. For the naïve student problem, I think the $\beta$'s should correspond to some "least-squares like" theoretical quantities.

Comment: But I do not believe the "theoretical" $\beta$'s need to be identified explicitly to solve the problem.

Comment: How about this: Let $\beta_0$, $\beta_1$ be the "true" quantities. Then $\epsilon = Y - \beta_0 - \beta_1 X$. Let $X|Y = 0 \sim p_0(x)$ and $X|Y=1 \sim p_1(x)$. Define RVs $X_0 \sim p_0(x)$ and $X_1 \sim p_1(x)$. Then $\epsilon \sim 1-\beta_0 - \beta_1X_1$ wp $p_1$ and $\epsilon \sim 0-\beta_0 - \beta_1X_0$ wp $p_0$. Hence $\epsilon$ has a mixture distribution.  Now, choose the two components of the mixture so that the result is a normal distribution. (Apparently this can be done!)

Comment: As I wrote, the least squares fit is wrong because of the correlation between the errors and regressors.  That's probably an instructive illustration by itself!

Comment: You can distinguish between a latent process with unknown parameters and normal errors and observable binary outcomes that emerge from that latent process. For example, here's [a utility-based derivation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/112058/7071) of the probit model.

Comment: This reply misses the point. The point is that the true errors of a regression model can be precisely normally distributed, even when Y is binary. The implications for theory and practice are respectively (a) the normality assumption should not be stated as " the errors are normal," but rather as "the errors are conditionally normal," or more directly, "Y is conditionally normal "; and for practice, one should not assume that normal appearance of the residuals (as seen in histogram or qq plot) implies that the normality assumption is reasonable.